# Unitary matrix knowing input and ouput states

Tags: qiskit, textbook-and-exercises

Input: n qubits after H gates.
Output, after measure: the n different bit strings of length 2^n with just one 1, with same probabilities.
Or said differently:
Input state |phi0>=(1,1,...1)/2^n
Output state |phi1>= (0,1,1,0,1,...,0)/n, with 1 on positions 2^k, k=0,2,...,n-1

Problem: find the unitary matrix that transforms |phi0> into |phi1>.
I have done it "manually" for n=2 and 3, but I am looking for something automatic (Qiskit code) for n>3.
Any suggestion?

Comment: $H^{\otimes n}$ generating $|1\rangle^{\otimes n}$ seems misleading. Also, please, try to write your question more formally.

Answer (score 0):

> Output, after measure: the $n$ different bit strings of length $2^n$ with just one $1$, with same probabilities

This is known as generalized [W-state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_state). There is a simple circuit to generate it starting from $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$.

The following Qiskit code snippet creates the circuit for any given $N$

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import numpy as np

circ = QuantumCircuit(N)
circ.x(N - 1)
for k in range(N - 1, 0, -1):
    theta = np.arccos(np.sqrt(1 / (k + 1)))
    circ.ry(-theta, k - 1)
    circ.cz(k, k - 1)
    circ.ry(theta, k - 1)

for k in range(1, N):
    circ.cx(N - k - 1, N - k)
```

The circuit plot for $N = 4$:

[image]

To check the output of the circuit:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

sv = Statevector.from_instruction(circ)
sv.draw('latex')
```

The result:
$$\frac{1}{2}|0001\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|0010\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|0100\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|1000\rangle$$

Comment: I think the question was intended for a map function of the kind $C(\mathbb{H}^{\otimes n})\rightarrow C(\mathbb{H}^{\otimes 2^n})$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the link.On the one hand I was starting after the H gates but, on the other hand, in my specific case I think I indeed can start from |0⟩⊗. So